# IEnumerable function returning null causing a value cannot be null exception

Tags: c#

The `GetAll` returns an `IEnumerable` and, in this case, it's `null`

```
List<TaskNote> notes = noteManager.GetAll(newTaskId).ToList();
```

I'm getting an error like the following:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   source'

Is this to be expected? Should I always check for null before doing a `ToList()`?

Comment: you should check null or you can  handle null in GetAll method. It is must.

Comment: You should fix the bug in GetAll, which should not be returning null.

Comment: Change `.ToList()` to `?.ToList()` as a short term measure. Then find the person who wrote `GetAll` and give them a mild smack to the head. They shouldn't be returned `null`. `null` and `Enumerable.Empty` are **not** the same thing. `null` means basically "there is no set of data", as opposed to "there is a set of data, but it is empty".

Comment: Are you returning null from `GetAll` ? Why?

Comment: @mjwills If you change the recommendation to `?.ToList() ?? new List<TaskNote>()` I'd tend to agree. Otherwise, we're just propagating nulls and will be the cause of someone else's headache in the future.

Comment: I don't disagree @Rob - but you have to read that comment in context. I mentioned it was a short-term measure, until you fix the underlying issue. _Don't just stop with the short-term measure for sure._

Comment: @mjwills And Rob, well, it depends on what c# version are you using.

Comment: You should avoid calling ToList() at all if you can help it. Many times you won't need it, or you can delay it until much later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gold rule: do not return null for collection types.

> Should I always check for null before doing a ToList()?

It depends on who is owner of `GetAll` method. If you - follow rule, if not - better to check.

Answer (score 6):

A best practice is to NEVER return null when returning a collection or enumerable. ALWAYS return an empty enumerable/collection.

You can easily return an empty enumerable instead of null.

```
public IEnumerable<Test> GetTest()
{
  return GetTestForMe() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Test>();
}
```

Using `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` can be seen as more efficient than returning null. Advantage is that `Enumerable.Empty` does not create an object on call so it will put less load on `GarbageCollector`.
`Enumerable.Empty<T>` caches the creation of the empty Collection, so the same Collection will be always be returned.

Comment: @mjwills Sorry, I meant null.

Comment: Enumerable.Empty<T> is better because it is more explicit.

Comment: Enumerable.Empty<T> caches the creation of the empty Collection, so the same Collection will be always be returned.

Comment: Huh, indeed you're right. Never knew that - thanks for the tidbit!

Answer (score 1):

```
List<TaskNote> notes = noteManager.GetAll(newTaskId)?.ToList();
```

this is short code to do NUll CHECK;